# ROS master URI is not set

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the procedure exactly in the Ubuntu ROS installation page. After installation in ubuntu 12.04 with rosbuild the command 'roscore' returns the error - "ROS master URI is not set".

The following lines are included in ~/.bashrc

**ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=""
ROS_DISTRO="groovy"
ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/groovy/etc/ros"
ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311"
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks"
ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros"
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash**

Please help me out

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198819/ros-master-uri-is-not-set/) by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2014-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What instructions did you follow? This should not be in your .bashrc. It should only have added:

```
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2